# Passing variable as reference in struct constructor in c++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have the following struct and I want to pass in the Buffer object as a reference so that I can push stuff inside a queue (Buffer class has a queue of strings) in when creating different threads. My problem is that the queue doesn't get updated by reference. Like the size still remains zero.

```
struct args{

Buffer buffer;

args( Buffer& rb){
    buffer = rb;

}
};
```

Here is my code for executing a function that adds element to the buffer:

```
void* addElement(void* arguments){
  args* myArgs = (args*) arguments;
  myArgs->buffer.push("John Smith);
}
```

Here is the code for creating a thread and adding strings to the buffer:

```
Buffer request_buffer;
pthread_t request_thread;
thread_args* argument = new args(request_buffer);
pthread_create(&request_thread,NULL,addElement,argument);
```

Comment: If you copy and paste those three code snippets into a file, and try to compile it, it does not compile.  If I fill in the missing pieces, it works on my machine... I may have omitted the bug under scrutiny.  A [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `args` struct has it's own `Buffer` object.  When you construct it, a copy of the buffer that is passed by reference is made.  When you add an element, it is added to the buffer that belongs to `argument`, and not `request_buffer`.

You fix this by declaring `buffer` to be a reference within the class:

```
struct args {
    Buffer &buffer;
    args(Buffer &rb): buffer(rb) { }
};
```

This will then store a reference to the buffer passed in to the constructor, so that when you add an element it will be added to that buffer (`request_buffer` in your example).